# Computational complexity in T(n) = Θ format

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

could someone explain what's the complexity in big theta format for this piece of code(and why)? It's my first assignment from this topic, and i'm a little bit confused. Any kind of help will be much appreciated!

```
for i <-- 1 to n-1
   do j <-- 1
     while j <= 2*(i+1)
       do j <-- j + 1
```

Comment: Any kind of help? Go and read your textbooks and lecture notes :-) Talk to your tutor/lecturer if necessary.

Comment: What are you reflexion this far ? What do you think about the "for" and the "while" to begin with ? What are the unitary complexities of the pieces you can extract from this ?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong with a ±1, but i think that the number of steps that will be executed is:

sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 2*(i+1) = 2sum_{i=1}^{n-1} + 2(n-1) = (n^2-n) + (2n-1) = n^2+n+1

Answer (score 0):

n^2 because you have a loop in a loop, so that means your instructions are executed n * n times

Comment: A "loop in a loop" doesn't always mean quadratic complexity.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your Pseudocode is not exactly correct according to the usual conventions.

```
for i <-- 1 to n-1
   do j <-- 1
     while j <= 2*(i+1)
       do j <-- j + 1
```

The above pseudocode should be more clear if represented as follows,

```
for i = 1 to n-1
    for j = 1 to (2*(i+1))
        // Body of the inner loop
```

The complexity of the above pseudocode can be analyzed only if the body of the inner loop contains constant time expressions. For example an addition or subtraction is a constant time operation if the operands are small enough. On the other hand if the loop contains a call to another function then the complexity also depends on the complexity of this called function.

If the body of the loop only contains constant time expressions then the complexity can be analyzed as follows.

The outer loop executes `n-1` times.
The inner loop executes `2*(i+1)` times.

So the statements inside the inner loop gets executed 4, 6, 8, ..., and finally 2n times. So the total number of instructions executed is,

```
4 + 6 + 8 + ... + 2n
= 2 ( 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + n)
= 2 (n(n+1)/2 - 1)
= n(n+1) - 2
```

There for the total number of instructions executed is , **n<sup>2</sup> - n - 2**.

Thus the complexity is **Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)**.